# Does JQuery have a sort_by function similar to Ruby's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

So given a list of items like so:

```
item_1 = {id:1, categories: {"category_A" => 1, "category_B" => {"sub_category_A" => 3, "sub_category_B" => 1}}}
item_2 = {id:2, categories: {"category_B" => {"sub_category_A" => 1, "sub_category_B" => 2}}}
```

Where the numeric value is that items order in a given sub or main category. Now, given a sub or main category, I want to sort the items by the order number. In Ruby I'd write...

```
# Given category_B and sub_category_A
items.sort_by { |i| i.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"] }

# which would return...
[item_2, item_1]
```

Also want to add, the key is if an item does NOT have the relevant passed category_B and sub_category_A, it should be excluded entirely from output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array#Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example) in JavaScript.

```
a.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"] - b.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"]
```

Is the comparison of 2 elements in Array.

**UPDATE**: to excluded from the output. You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) it before sorting

Let's see my example

```js
var arr = [{
      id:1, 
      categories: 
      {
        "category_A" : 1, 
        "category_B" : {
          "sub_category_A" : 3, 
          "sub_category_B" : 1
          }
         }
      },{
      id:3, 
      categories: {
        "category_C" : {
          "sub_category_A" : 1, 
          "sub_category_B" : 2
          }
      }
    },{
      id:2, 
      categories: {
        "category_B" : {
          "sub_category_A" : 1, 
          "sub_category_B" : 2
          }
      }
    }];

    var result = arr.filter(a => a.categories["category_B"])
                    .sort((a, b) => {
      return a.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"] - b.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"];
    })

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: how would you further amend the sort to account for items which may not have a category_b?

Comment: See my edit answer. You can filter the array before sorting

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery; JavaScript arrays have a `filter()` function you can use to limit yourself to valid items and a `sort()` function that can take a comparing function as its argument:

```
var item_1 = {
    id:1, 
    categories: {
        "category_A" : 1,
        "category_B" : {
            "sub_category_A" : 3,
            "sub_category_B" : 1
        }
    }
};
var item_2 = {
    id:2,
    categories: {
        "category_B" : {
            "sub_category_A" : 1,
            "sub_category_B" : 2
        }
    }
};

var item_3 = {
    id: 3,
    categories : {
        "category_A" : 2
    }
};

[item_1,item_2,item_3].filter(function(entry) {
  return entry.categories.category_B;}).sort(function(left, right) {
  return left.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"] -
    right.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"]
});

// or in the more readable ES6 style
[item_1,item_2,item_3]
    .filter((entry) => entry.categories.category_B)
    .sort((left, right) =>  left.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"] - right.categories["category_B"]["sub_category_A"]
);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: how would you further amend the sort to account for items which may not have a category_b?

Answer (score 0):

Neither ECMAScript nor jQuery have `sortBy`, but [LoDash does](https://lodash.com/docs/#sortBy) and so does [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy).

It's also not hard to supply your own:

```js
Array.prototype.sortBy = function sortBy(keyFn) {
  const compare = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
  return this.
    map(el => [keyFn(el), el]).
    sort(([a, ], [b, ]) => compare(a, b)).
    map(([, el]) => el);
};

const item1 = { id: 1, categories: { category_A: 1, category_B: { sub_category_A: 3, sub_category_B: 1 }}};
const item2 = { id: 2, categories: { category_B: { sub_category_A: 1, sub_category_B: 2 }}};

const sorted = [item1, item2].sortBy(el => el.categories.category_B.sub_category_A);

console.log(sorted);
```